# Custom formula in Data Validation not allowing me to "Save"

Tags: validation, google-sheets, save, google-sheets-formula, formula

```js
=IF(VLOOKUP(B10,({'Roster Data'!B:B,'Roster Data'!A:A}),2,FALSE="WR",'Roster Data'!H2:H11,'Roster Data'!G2:G11)
```

When I put this formula into the CUSTOM FORMULA option for DATA VALIDATION, I hit the SAVE button but it doesn't save. Is there something wrong with my formula or am I just writing the formula wrong for the DATA VALIDATION process.

Basically, if a PLAYERS POSITION is RB, I want the DATA VALIDATION to go to the RB list and if the PLAYERS POSITION is a WR, I want the DATA VALIDATION to go to the WR list.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula is wrong.

Use this one and see if it works for you

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B10,{'Roster Data'!B:B,'Roster Data'!A:A},2,0)="WR",'Roster Data'!H2:H11,'Roster Data'!G2:G11)
```

Comment: So now the data validation is letting me save it, (I now realize that I think I was missing a parenthesis) but now its saying there is nothing in the range. I have double checked and all my ranges are correct. Do IF statements work in Data Validation? or are they done/written differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can't include references to other pages in formula fields in google sheets. You can either to the computation and select the range on another page as a list or have helper columns on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

for Data Validation applies the same rules as for Conditional Formatting... referencing range from different sheet needs to be indirected. therefore the correct formula should be:

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B10, {INDIRECT("Roster Data!B:B"), INDIRECT("Roster Data!A:A")}, 2, 0))="WR", 
 INDIRECT("Roster Data!H2:H11"), INDIRECT("Roster Data!G2:G11"))
```

[image]

and such formula can be used here for validation purposes:

[image]

if you want to use it here for dropdown purposes:

[image]

that is not possible and you will need to do it like this:

[image]